# SQL Select Statement With Multiple Tables If Value Exists

Tags: sql

**location_data table**:

```
id (pk) 
lng
lat
```

**voting_data table**:

```
id (pk)
location_id (= location_data.id)
vote
```

This is the current shortened query I have to retrieve my location data which gets encoded into JSON.

```
SELECT 
     `id`, `lat`, `lng`, 
     (6371 * acos(cos(radians('%s')) * cos(radians(lat)) * 
      cos(radians(lng) - radians('%s')) + sin(radians('%s')) * 
      sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM 
    location_data 
HAVING 
    distance < 50
```

Some locations have additional "vote data" which I want to encode as well into JSON (paired along with the corresponding location) but only if they exist (VoteData.LocationID = LocationData.ID).

Pseudo code: get all `LocationData` with distance condition -> if certain location has matching voting data (VoteData.LocationID = LocationData.ID), add to the list -> Encode into JSON

Not sure how to do this though...thanks in advance.

Comment: What is matching vote data and why would that even affect the query you want?

Comment: Matching would mean VoteData.LocationID = LocationData.ID. I thought it would be easier to do this in one query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a basic join would work here:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.lat, t1.lng,
       (6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( t1.lat ) ) * cos( radians( t1.lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( t1.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance,
       COALESCE(t2.vote, 'NA') AS voting_data
FROM location_data t1
LEFT JOIN voting_data t2
    ON t1.id = t2.location_id
HAVING distance < 50
```

This would filter off any location not within a radius of 50km.  And records which have no matching `vote` data would return `'NA'`.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the voting_data table in your query on location_data.id = voting_data.location_id